# Display block based on main content type with view

Tags: views, entities, 7, blocks

I have created a view in a block, to display some related information to the current content type being displayed into the block. More precisely, I want to display the block only for book pages.

What I did is to add a contextual filter based on content type. 
For "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE", I provide a default value for "PHP contextual filter code" as follows

```
$node = node_load(arg(1));
return $node->type;
```

For "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS AVAILABLE", I use "Specify validation criteria" for content types with "book page".

I tried [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74242/switch-views-or-hide-block-based-on-content-type) but it didn't work. I think because I am using aliases in the url, it does not work.

What am I missing?

P.S: My final goal is actually to extract the group audience from the current book page and display the admins of that group into the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you don't need to provide any default value with PHP code.

Remove your contextual filter and add new one: `Content: nid`.

**"WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE"**

Provide default value -> content ID from URL

**"When the filter value IS available or a default is provided"**

Specify validation criteria

Validator -> Content -> book

Answer (score 1):

Why are you checking the content type with the view?

If I understood your question, you want to display the view's block only on certain content type ('Book').
A much easier solution will be:

1. Go to Dashboard >> Structure >> Blocks
2. Find the view's block and go to its configuration
3. Under the 'Content Types' tab add 'Book'

That is it!

[image: Block configuration page]